# Is a GPU accelerated Quantum computer simulator publishable research?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, simulations, quantum-computer

I have built a GPU accelerated quantum computer simulator that is quicker then libquantum and the IBM QISkit simumators. Is the work done on this (methods, archetecture) publishable?

Comment: Try SPIE.  Their journals are application oriented.

Comment: It most probably is. Have a look at this (published) paper for example: https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.04929

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the publishing ecosystem for quantum computing papers, but I would guess that this is very much a methods paper - no suited for the theory journals, but certainly relevant to the ones with more practical papers.

As a general pattern papers demonstrating new methods or tools tend to be well cited even if they are rarely held in high regard (perhaps unjustly), so from a CV standpoint it might be worthwhile to publish.